# Adding window.bluetooth object to Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, bluetooth, npapi

I want to demo a web page being used to interact with a physical object in the same proximity as a web-enabled device (Mac/Windows/Linux laptop). In order to do this, I want to create my own `window.bluetooth` object in Javascript that will provide an interface to the host device's Bluetooth controller via the Serial Port Profile. For now it's just a demo, but I might want to develop a generic API to abstract Bluetooth drivers in Javascript.

I'm not particularly concerned with portability or generic solutions at this point. I just want to see if it would work on my laptop with a device I'm building using a [BlueSMiRF Silver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10269) modem. I know Google Chrome extensions are capable of [injecting Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) into every page the user visits, and [NPAPI](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) is capable of compiling native OS code into a form that can communicate with Javascript. It looks like someone has done something [vaguely similar](https://code.google.com/p/browntooth/source/browse/branches/communicator-extension-patch/extension/npapi/SConstruct?spec=svn9&r=9) before with slightly more specific applications.

My question is, is a Chrome extension with NPAPI the best way to do this? Alternatives could be Flash or a Java applet, but those are kind of 1996 solutions. Here are the metrics I use to evaluate a solution:

- Feasibility. Is it possible?
- Ease of development. How many lines of code would it take?
- Leverage. Does anything else out there already do something similar?

For those of you thinking it's preposterous for the browser to monitor lower-level network status, it's [already been done](http://html5demos.com/offline) with Wi-Fi.

Comment: Not encouraging users to install Java is a good thing, but what are the actual arguments against doing this with Flash? If it can be done with an existing plugin with a big install base, you get around distribution issues, avoid another attack vector, probably save yourself a lot of time, ...

Comment: If it is feasible for you to write a Chrome App instead of a web page, you can use chrome.bluetooth API (https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/bluetooth.html).